# uploading image to mysql database

Tags: php, mysqli

hello i try to upload form information to database and every field is uploaded Except image file and the image moved to the path but when i check the table there is no image name in the image column   ... my code :

```
$server   = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root3";
$dbname   = "sampledb";

// creat connection
$connection = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $dbname);

// check the connection
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("connect to database failed :" . $connection->connect_error);
}
 // check value from select menu 
if ($_POST['typelist'] == 'item') {
    // prepare and bind parameters
    if (isset($_FILES['item_image'])) {
        $itemquery = $connection->prepare("insert into items(item_image,  item_manufacturing_year, item_Length, item_width, item_weight, item_price, item_description, item_model) VALUES (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)");
        $itemquery->bind_param("bsssssss", $image, $manufacturing_year, $length, $width, $weight, $price, $description, $model);

        // set all parameters and execute the query
        $image = $_FILES['item_image']['name'];
        $temp  = $_FILES['item_image']['tmp_name'];
        $path  = "../images/items/$image";
        move_uploaded_file($temp, $path);
        $manufacturing_year = $_POST['manufacturing_year'];
        $length      = $_POST['item_length'];
        $width       = $_POST['item_width'];
        $weight      = $_POST['item_weight'];
        $price       = $_POST['item_price'];
        $description = $_POST['item_description'];
        $model       = $_POST['item_model'];
        $itemquery->execute();
        $itemquery->close();
        $connection->close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: And why do you use `b` and passing a string in a `bind_param`?

Comment: Try putting `$itemquery->bind_param` on the line after you define `$model`.

Comment: @RC you think wrong.

Comment: b for blob and s for string

Comment: `$image` is a string. What is `blob` doing here?

Comment: @u_mulder this "syntax" is so not usual

Comment: in items table the type of image column is blob

Comment: judging by his question and the syntax he used, im assuming hes trying to store the image itself in the database.

Comment: If column type is `blob` why do you expect it to store `image name`?

Comment: ok i make it s instead of b and it is working but how worked and the type of column is blob ??

Comment: sorry i am new to php  please i need answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you was setting the image name after to bind the parameters on the query, try in this way:

```
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root3";
$dbname = "sampledb";

// creat connection
$connection = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $dbname);

// check the connection
if ($connection->connect_error)
{
     die("connect to database failed :" . $connection->connect_error);
}

// check value from select menu 
if ($_POST['typelist'] == 'item') 
{

  // prepare and bind parameters
  if (isset($_FILES['item_image'])) 
  {

    // set all parameters FIRST TO BIND ON THE QUERY
    $image = $_FILES['item_image']['name']; // Now you have the image name
    $temp = $_FILES['item_image']['tmp_name'];
    $path = "../images/items/$image";

    move_uploaded_file($temp, $path);

    $manufacturing_year = $_POST['manufacturing_year'];
    $length = $_POST['item_length'];
    $width = $_POST['item_width'];
    $weight = $_POST['item_weight'];
    $price = $_POST['item_price'];
    $description = $_POST['item_description'];
    $model = $_POST['item_model'];

    $itemquery = $connection->prepare("insert into items(item_image,  item_manufacturing_year, item_Length, item_width, item_weight, item_price, item_description, item_model) VALUES (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)");
    $itemquery->bind_param("bsssssss", $image, $manufacturing_year, $length, $width, $weight, $price, $description, $model);

    $itemquery->execute();
    $itemquery->close();
    $connection->close();
  } 
 }
```

Try to use a var_dump() php function to see if the image name value is right. As you were doing, probably the image name was setting as null.